# flutter : How i can open folder after i created it in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to open the folder that I created using flutter

[image: create folder]framework.

Comment: Please refrain from posting code in the form of images.

Answer (score 0):

```
getFiles() async {
  try {
    var dir = Directory('/data/user/0/com.example.demo/your created folder name');
    if (dir.existsSync()) {
      List dataList = dir.listSync();
      for (var element in dataList) {
        print('get filePath: $element');
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('error: $e');
  }
}
```

Comment: i want open folder not file.